# How to show products of a special category in left panel in home page in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to show products of a special category in left panel in home page.For that i have created a category in admin and added some products under that.But i don't know how to show in left panel of home page.

If anyone knows this,Please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in the layout xml for the homepage to display the product list for that special category:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="mycatblock" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <action method="setData"><name>category_id</name><value>YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_HERE</value></action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

Note: this will display the products in the default template structure. You can pass your template file path in the above code to display it as per your need.

Alternatively, If you want to display it somewhere else in the content area on the homepage then you can simply use following line in the content section of home page(CMS page) in the admin panel:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="YOUR_CATEGORY_ID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

go to your theme/layout/catalog.xml

under  tag under

```
<reference name="left">

  <block type="core/template" name="left.cat.product" template="custom/leftsideproduct.phtml">

</reference>
```

now go to your theme/template folder create a folder of name custom and create a file leftsideproduct.phtml

```
<?php     $catid=3; //go to admin click on category you have created check id and use here
    $category_prd = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);


                                }?>
                                <?php $prodCollection = $category_prd->getProductCollection();
                                foreach ($prodCollection as $product) 
                                {
                                $prdIds[] = $product->getId(); //Array to store all the product ids
                                }



                                $allProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                                          ->getCollection()
                                          ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $prdIds))
                                          ->addAttributeToSelect('price')->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('image')->addAttributeToSelect('id');

                                foreach($allProducts as $product):?>





                                    <?php echo $product->getId();?>">
                                        <?php echo $product->getName();?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(150,150);?>"  title="<?php echo $product->getName();?>


                        <?php endforeach;?>
```

now go to admin under cms page click on homepage set layout 2columns-leftside bar and save it now check.
don't forget to like my ans if it was helpful